# Using variables in MYSQL SELECT WHERE query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to include variables in my MYSQL SELECT WHERE query.
I want to be able to use variables, as well as the false symbol "!="

For example:

```
select * from XXX
where id != '$id'
```

Why is this not working, and how can I make this work?

Comment: If your entire query is contained in double quotes, you may insert variables in your query string. If not, they must be appended with a dot. `'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . ' WHERE ...'`

Comment: See this: php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Answer (score 4):

It's better you use mysqli prepared statement or PDO since mysql_* functions are deprecated in recent PHP versions. Check how your query looks with mysqli prepared statement.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * XXX WHERE id != ?");

$stmt->bind_param( "d", $value); 
// 'd' is a format integer, for string use 's'

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($col1);
// then fetch and close the statement
```

Comment: Please, never interpolate the variables directly into SQL; this is the leading cause of [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Yes Yuki, I've mentioned both, a direct answer of OP's question and also a suggestion

Comment: Yes, but you haven't mentioned *why* your suggestion is very worthwhile! :)

Comment: The "suggestion" here is actually more or less a requirement.  If you don't write things this way, hackers are going to pwn your site, pretty much guaranteed at some point.

Comment: Please consider removing everything before the "SUGGESTION" (which is the actual correct answer). A few decades of spreading awful code is enough.

Comment: @AlexB - Removed those vulnerable queries. :)

Answer (score -1):

As you are asking how can pass variable id in mysql query so check below, other wise so many guys have answered you for php etc.

```
set @id=4;
select * from XXX
where id != @id;
```

Comment: dear -ve voter, I already mentioned in my answer that it is if he want to do it in pure in mysql..is there any problem in syntax..

Answer (score -4):

If you are using this code in php, you can use this

```
$query = "select * from XXX where id != {$id}";
```

OR

```
$query = "select * from XXX where id != '".$id."'";
```

If you are trying to use these variables in phpmyadmin, I think that is not possible.